# Not able to load images on Github pages Blog post

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I wanted to publish a blog post, which contains a plot. I am perfectly able to view and load the image in markdown, but when I try to publish to on my github pages, I can see everything perfectly except for the plot. Here is my [Github repo](https://github.com/Arjitkp/arjitkp.github.io) for my blog and here is the [markdown file](https://github.com/Arjitkp/arjitkp.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2017-8-15-DV.md) I wish to post online.

In the above post I am trying to display the image with: `![](DV_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png)` having the image located at `_posts/DV_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a folder to hold your posts images at root level

   ```
   mkdir images
   ```
2. Move the directory structure containing the images to the above folder

   ```
   mv _posts/DV_files/ images/
   ```
3. Use the new path and use `absolute_url` to generate the full url

   ```
   ![]({{"/images/DV_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-2-1.png"|absolute_url}})
   ```

Now your images will appear in the post.

Comment: I tried as per your instructions. But it turns out not only am I not able to to see my images on post, the images now doesnt load on .md file either. [MD file](https://github.com/Arjitkp/arjitkp.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2017-08-15-DV.md) [Github Rep](https://github.com/Arjitkp/arjitkp.github.io)

Comment: UPDATE: I just refreshed again, and I can now see my image. Thanks a lot. :)